# Format translator field -- suppress by, biblatex, authoryear

Tags: biblatex, authoryear

I am formatting a bibliography for a journal that insists on lots of stupid changes to standard styles, using biblatex. The closest to what they want is AuthorYear, so I am starting from that. I have got most of it done, but two things remain. I am putting them in separate questions as they are sufficiently different.

For entries with a translator, I currently get:

> Croce, Benedetto (1902). Aesthetic. Trans. by D. Ainslie (1909). Noonday.

What I need is:

> Croce, Benedetto (1902). Aesthetic. Trans. D. Ainslie (1909). Noonday.

How do I suppress the "by" in all entries using a translator (all entry types)?

I think I should be able to work this out myself given all the other tinkering I have done, but I've been at this for hours now and I'm exhausted!

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz pointed out, without a proper MWE it is hard to answer your questions correctly.

With the informations you provided I would suggest that you edit the `bytranslator` bibstring. Your example looks like it is rendered in english. So you could try adding the following to your praeamble:

```latex
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
    bytranslator = {trans\adddot},
}
```

You might have to change `english` to the language you're setting with `babel` or `polyglossia`.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Comment: `bytranslator = {trans\adddot},` would be better than `bytranslator = {trans.},`, because `biblatex`/LaTeX distinguishes full stops/periods (sentence-ending periods) and dots (abbreviation dots). Normally a `.` is interpreted as a full stop so that you need `\adddot` when you want an abbreviation dot as is the case here.

Comment: @moewe of course, you're right. Edited.